# Best way to implement a connection between a smartphone and a webpage on a pc

Tags: android, ios, network-programming

I am looking for an existing library to establish a connection between any smartphone(android/ios/win phone) and a web page.
Sort of what whatsapp is using (https://web.whatsapp.com/), with authentication.

Once the connection is established, i will have to send real time data ( audio and text) from the phone to the pc.

I suppose that whatsApp use a server to relay the data. i dont mind doing the authentication with the help of a server but once the connection is ok,**I prefer to do all the communication on wifi instead of sending data from the phone to a server and sending it back to the web page on the pc.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to solve a particular problem which is already solved, You don't want to reinvent the wheel(especially in web) but use the existing solution.

What you are looking for is [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC). Fits exactly for your use case. But i am not sure about the development efforts required for this.

There are Client libraries in almost all languages. A quick search gave this for [Android](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC)

And i am not sure about the device support you are expecting, check [Caniuse?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection)

Also have a look at [WiFi-p2p](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) for android.

**UPDATE:**

check this webrtc website for cross platform [development support and examples](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development).

Comment: thanks! I will check for cross platform possibilities

Answer (score 0):

There is no real "best" way of doing this, but you have to have a server of some type running on your computer. From there you can use normal network requests from Android to communicate with your computer as long as they are on the same network (WiFi). https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html